# SFML 2.4 Window doesn't display shapes

Tags: c++, sfml

I tried writing the program myself, copying it from the official site and watching tutorials. Nothing helped. The problem is that the window doesn't display anything. Here is an example:

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window( sf::VideoMode( 600, 600 ), "SFML WORK!" );
    sf::CircleShape circle(150);
    circle.setRadius(200);
    circle.setPointCount(300);
    while ( window.isOpen( ) )
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while ( window.pollEvent( event ) )
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }
        window.clear( );
        window.draw(circle);
        window.display( );
    } 
    }
```

It should, and in the tutorial it does, show a circle. In my case it just shows a white screen. Any ideas how to fix this? The program build is successfull, no errors found.

Comment: When I take this code, compile it and execute it, I can see a white circle on a black background. Maybe you can check your installation of SFML on your computer

Comment: I have an error message in the console: "Failed to activate window's context", but the program runs(just a white screen)

Comment: @EmirKhalilov What version of SFML are you using? Is your SFML's architecture the same as your program's target architecture? Are you doing anything with threads that you've omitted from your example?